# Delphi Android 12: Lost access to database in SharedDocumentsPath

Tags: android, delphi

In an App I use locally, after upgrading to Delphi 11.2, I had to un-install the App and re-install it.
I now get an 'access denied' on my own database tree, containing critical data, and which is stored in the "SharedDocumentsPath".

I can simply copy this data using a filemanager, even have it copied to my Windows PC, but whatever I try, I can no longer access it from the App itself.
This seems to be a security issue from Android 11 onwards. Documentation says that I also need to request
android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
which I have done. But it makes no difference.

### Then I found this reference:
Test scoped storage

To enable scoped storage in your app, regardless of your app's target SDK version and manifest flag values, enable the following app compatibility flags:

```
DEFAULT_SCOPED_STORAGE (enabled for all apps by default)
FORCE_ENABLE_SCOPED_STORAGE (disabled for all apps by default)
```

### To disable scoped storage and use the legacy storage model instead, unset both flags.

But I have no idea how to go about this in Delphi.

What do I have to set up (in Delphi) to get access to my database back?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get access to my data back, by forcing the manifest targetSdkVersion="29"...